# Creating and generating HTML File with jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, ajax

Here i want to Create this little data into HTML file like **nafiz** by using this ajax.and the ajax function is calling by clicking by the button.but it is not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">


           function GetHTmlGenerateList() {
              // var crthtml = $("#TextArea1").val();
               var crthtml = "<b>nafiz</b>";
               GenerateHtmlList = new HtmlGenerate(crthtml);
               alert(GenerateHtmlList);

               $.ajax({
                   beforeSend: function () {
                       // show image here
                       $('#loadBusy').show();
                   },
                   complete: function () {
                       // hide image here<a href="../../RelatedCategory/">../../RelatedCategory/</a>
                       $('#loadBusy').hide();
                   },
                   type: "POST",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   url: window.location.origin + "/Service/AdminService/CategoryHtmlGenerator.asmx" + "/InfoGenerate",
                   //paramiter Input
                   data: JSON.stringify({ aGenerateHtmlList: GenerateHtmlList }),
                   dataType: "json",
                   async: true,
                   cache: false,
                   success: function (data) {
                       var resultData = result['d'];
                       document.getElementById("lblSystemMessage").innerHTML = "Saved";

                   },
                   error: function (x, e) {
                       console.log(x);
                       console.log(e);
                   }
               });
           }

   </script>
```

here is the method

```
public void InfoGenerate(GenerateHtmlList aGenerateHtmlList)
    {

   // GenerateHtmlList aGenerateHtmlList = new GenerateHtmlList();
    string FileName = "nafiz.html";
    string HTMLGenarator = "";

    HTMLGenarator = "<html>" +
                     "<body style='margin:0px 0px 0px 0px!important;'>" +
                     "<div style='float:left;width:100%!important;height:100%!important;margin:0px;padding:0px;'>" +
                 aGenerateHtmlList.Createhtml
                    +
                     "</div>" +

                     "</body>" +
                     "</html>";



    string pathOfFile = Server.MapPath(@"../../Images/Files/HTML/" + FileName);
    if (File.Exists(pathOfFile))
    {
        this.CopyFile(FileName);
        this.DeleteFile(FileName);
    }
    this.CreateHTMLFile(FileName, HTMLGenarator);

}
```

public class GenerateHtmlList
    {
        public string Createhtml { get; set; }
    }

And CREATEHTML method is

```
public void CreateHTMLFile(string HTMLFileName, string Content)
{
    string destinationPath = Server.MapPath(@"../../Images/Files/HTML/" + HTMLFileName);
    string htmlDocument = Content;
    FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(destinationPath);
    StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    streamWriter.Write(htmlDocument);
    streamWriter.Close();
}
```

And I am intializing this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function HtmlGenerate(crthtml) {
           this.Createhtml = crthtml;
       }
   </script>
```

Comment: what is the actual problem?

Comment: My problem is html file is not creating in my destination folder saying it in my ajax error.

Answer (score 0):

Either you did not show it or you do not have a part of your code where you assing action onClick to the button. That is what I understood from your problem that the function is not being called when you click on the button.

Comment: <button type="button" id="htmlButton" class="btn btn-success custom" onclick="GetHTmlGenerateList()">Generate</button>

are you meaning this sir???owenek1 are you saying that my method  and function is not working in that ajax